# unable to fetch date column from ms access db. node-adodb node module used

Tags: node.js, ms-access, adodb

I've noticed an issue with date fields not being returned in the result of a query.

I am using "version": "2.0.2"

my date column (column name - AcctDate and table name - AccountingLog) date format is - *1/2/1970 3:46:25 PM *
my query is:

```
SELECT MAX(AccountingLog.AcctDate) FROM AccountingLog WHERE AccountingLog.UserId = "'+userID+'"'
```

I also tried this query also: `SELECT * FROM AccountingLog`

using above queries unable to capture date column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same issue. Google provided me no good results for the issue. 
I figured out the issue in the adodb.js file.
Ms access returns varDate type for date fields and varDate type does not allow toString() and thus it fails to convert date field.

```
/**
* Fill records array
* @param recordset
* @returns {Array}
*/
function fillRecords(recordset){
  var item, records = [],
  count = recordset.Fields.Count;
  // Not empty
  if (!recordset.BOF || !recordset.EOF) {
    recordset.MoveFirst();

    while (!recordset.EOF) {
      item = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var field = recordset.Fields.Item(i);
          item[field.name] = field.toString(); // CODE FAILS HERE FOR 'varDate'
        }
      records.push(item);
      recordset.MoveNext();
    }
  }
  return records;
}
```

I added check for date column names(ms access db fields) into the above function. So that when the recordset.Field is varDate then first varDate will be converted to new Date() and then applied string conversion. Please find the code snippet below.

```
function fillRecords(recordset){
  var item, records = [],
  count = recordset.Fields.Count;
  // Not empty
  if (!recordset.BOF || !recordset.EOF) {
    recordset.MoveFirst();

    while (!recordset.EOF) {
      item = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var field = recordset.Fields.Item(i);
        // ADDED below condition.
        if(field.name === "ActivationTime" || field.name === "CreateDate")
        {
          var dateYear = new Date(field.value);
          item[field.name] = dateYear.toString();
        }else{
          item[field.name] = field.value;
        }

      }
      records.push(item);
      recordset.MoveNext();
    }
  }
  return records;
}
```